# ObservedObject, derived from Json, not loading into Picker, but loads in List. In SwiftUI, Xcode 11

Tags: json, swiftui, xcode11, picker, observedobject

I'm new to mobile development, and in the process of learning SwiftUI.

I've been struggling to figure out what's wrong with my picker. I am successfully returning the data from my URLSession, adding it to my model. I can confirm this by adding my @ObservedObject to a List, which returns all of the items. Putting the same @ObservedObject into a picker returns an empty picker for some reason. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Here's my view with the Picker(). When run, the Picker is empty. I can comment out the Picker(), leaving just the ForEach() with Text(), and the text appears.

```
import Foundation
import Combine
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

@ObservedObject var countries = CulturesViewModel()
@State private var selectedCountries = 0

    var body: some View {

        VStack {

            //loop through country array and add them to picker
            Picker(selection: $selectedCountries, label: Text("Select Your Country")) {
                ForEach(0 ..< countries.cultures.count, id: \.self) { post in
                    Text(self.countries.cultures[post].Culture).tag(post)
               }
            }.labelsHidden()     
        }

    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Here's my ViewModel. It set's the @Published variable to the results of the JSON request in the WebService(). If I hard-code the @Published variable to the value that's begin returned, the Picker works.

```
import Foundation
import Combine
import SwiftUI

class CulturesViewModel: ObservableObject {
    init() {
        fetchCultures()
    }

    @Published var cultures = [Culture](){
        didSet {
            didChange.send(self)
        }
    }

    private func fetchCultures(){
        WebService().GetCultures {
            self.cultures = $0
        }
    }

    let didChange = PassthroughSubject<CulturesViewModel, Never>()
}
```

Here's my WebService(). Unfortunately, I'm unable to share the JSON url, I've added in the json that's returned.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class WebService {

    func GetCultures(completion: @escaping([Culture]) ->()) {

        guard let url = URL("")

        [
            {
                "CultureId": 0,
                "Culture": "Select Your Country"
            },
            {
                "CultureId": 1078,
                "Culture": "English (United States)"
            },
            {
                "CultureId": 6071,
                "Culture": "English (Canada)"
            }
        ]

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data,_,_) in
            do {
                if let data = data {
                    let culturesList = try JSONDecoder().decode([Culture].self, from: data)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completion(culturesList)
                    }
                } else {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completion([])
                    }
                }

            } catch {
                print(error)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion([])
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Lastly, here's my Model.

```
import Foundation

struct Culture: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var CultureId: Int
    var Culture: String
}
```

Comment: `@StateObject var countries = CulturesViewModel()` would be more appropriate here since you initialize `countries` right away

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The work around to make the picker refresh is to add a unique id. Refreshing (or) reloading the countries, will create a new UUID for the picker items. This will force the picker to refresh. I've modified your code to include an id.

```
//loop through country array and add them to picker
Picker(selection: $selectedCountries, label: Text("Select Your Country")) {
    ForEach(0 ..< countries.cultures.count, id: \.self) { post in
        Text(self.countries.cultures[post].Culture).tag(post)
   }
}.labelsHidden()
.id(UUID())
```

This seems to be a known issue with the picker.

Comment: Thank you. I spent hours searching for an answer, but couldn't find anything. Answer accepted.